# How to convert dt.datetime into isoformat to use in the following api call?

Tags: python, api, datetime, python-requests

I have to call api in the following manner:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
response= requests.get("https://api.com/?device_id=1&timestamp__gte=2021-09-01T18:30:00Z&timestamp__lte=2021-09-02T18:30:00Z",auth = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'password'))
```

I have to use variables start and end as input for timestamp__gte and timestamp__lte. The start variable is in the following format: datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0).

```
print(start)
#->datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

I am using the following method to convert this to iso format:

```
start=start.isoformat()
start= start+'Z'
print(start)
#->'2022-01-01T00:00:00Z'
```

I am putting the iso format converted start and end in my api call but I am still getting <Response[500]>.

```
response = requests.get("https://api.com/?device_id=1&timestamp__gte=start&timestamp__lte=end",auth = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'password'))
print(response)
#-> <Response[500]>
```

Probably because timestamp__gte= 2022-01-01T00:00:00Z is the required input instead of '2022-01-01T00:00:00Z'. How do I convert start and end variables to the desired format to ensure that my api call works?

Comment: Please, show the actual code for the request with using variable. Also you may want to check how to pass query parameters to get(), instead of incorporating them in URL

Comment: This code works when I put timestamp__lte and timestamp__gte manually. Also, I'll need to give my username and password for you to work on the actual code.

Comment: We don't need your credentials - e.g. like you did with hardcoded example. Obviously the request you make is incorrect.

Comment: The request gives the correct response when I enter the parameters manually. I have not used the correct url here. My question is related to the format of the timestamp variables.

Comment: Your problem is the request you make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
response= requests.get("https://api.com/?device_id=1&timestamp__gte=start&timestamp__lte=end",auth = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'password'))
```

With this line you pass `'start'` as parameter, not the value of `start` variable.

One way is to construct the URL with f-string:

```
url = f"https://api.com/?device_id=1&timestamp__gte={start}&timestamp__lte={end}"
response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'password'))
```

However, as I said you should be using

```
base_url = 'https://api.com/'
payload = {'device_id':1,
           'timestamp__gte':start,
           'timestamp__lte':end}
response = requests.get(base_url, data=payload, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'password'))
```

[check the docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)

Note, this does not discuss potential time-zone issues with your `start` and `end` datetime objects that may affect the actual vs expected API response.

Answer (score 0):

probably you need to convert to the server timezone

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from tzlocal import get_localzone

local_tz = get_localzone()
timestamp = '1643533570'
local_datetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).astimezone(local_tz)

datestring = "2022-01-30 00:00:00"
utc_datetime = datetime.fromisoformat(datestring).astimezone(timezone.utc)
local_datetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(datestring).astimezone(local_tz)
print(utc_time.isoformat(timespec='seconds'))
```

please recheck on your request

```
requests.get(url=url, headers={'user': username, 'password': password}, data={'start':'datestring', 'end':'datestring2'})
```

Comment: TypeError: timezone() argument 1 must be datetime.timedelta, not str

Comment: i made change, pls check

Comment: I guess you would need to put the start and end inside the body, not the header.   requests.get(url, headers, data=body)